# custom url for taxonomy > vocabulary at Drupal 6

Tags: url, drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy, vocabulary

I'm new at Drupal. a question;

I create a hotels directory site. I created Taxonomy>Vocabulary for locations like London, Liverpool, etc... For example the url below lists the London

```
localhost/drupal/taxonomy/term/1
```

how can change that url to something like

```
localhost/drupal/hotels/london
```

is it possible? appreciate advices so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable the `path` module in Drupal core, and download and enable the `pathauto` module from the Drupal modules website. You can use pathauto to set rules over how you wish to rewrite the paths of your taxonomy pages, and you can certainly do something like this.

I am guessing that to achieve the URL alias you are suggesting, the rewrite rules would look something like:

`[vocab-raw]/[cat-raw]`

Assuming that your vocabulary is called Hotels, and the term is called London.

Comment: hey thanks for help! I already had pathauto actually, just now wanted to follow your advise but I can't see Pathauto under my Site Configuration :( Path and Pathauto is enabled, but I don't have any particular Pathauto configuration page :/ am i missing anything?

Comment: Open the configuration page for `URL Aliases`, there is a tab at the top right labelled `Automated alias settings`. It links to `example.com/admin/build/path/pathauto`

Comment: great help! thanks Finbarr! my current settings http://img.skitch.com/20100518-fi1pc51igiwm8de4g497mn9ybh.jpg and I change it [vocab-raw]/[cat-raw], but nothing changes at front-end, it still links as taxonomy/term/1 :/

Comment: You will need to bulk generate the url aliases. In the taxonomy term path settings fieldset on the automated alias settings page, check the box that reads `Bulk generate aliases for terms that are not aliased`, then hit `save configuration` at the bottom.

Comment: wowowow! love it! Appreciate for your patience and big support for my silly questions :)  working great now :)